# How do I create a partitioned collection in Cosmos DB with pydocumentdb?

Tags: python, azure, azure-cosmosdb

The `pydocumentdb.document_client.DocumentClient` object has a `CreateCollection()` method, defined [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-python/blob/master/pydocumentdb/document_client.py#L332).

When creating a collection with this method, one needs to specify the database link (already known), the collection (I don't know how to reference it if it hasn't been made) and options.

Parameters that I would like to control when creating the collection are:

- name of collection
- type of collection (fixed size vs. partitioned)
- partition keys
- RU value
- Indexing policy (or at least be able to create a default template somewhere and automatically copy it to the newly created one)

Enums for some of these parameters seem to be defined [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-python/blob/master/pydocumentdb/documents.py), but I don't see any potentially useful HTTP headers in [http_constants.py](https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-python/blob/master/pydocumentdb/http_constants.py), and I don't see where RUs come in to play or where a cohesive "Collection" object would be passed as a parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could refer to the `source sample code` from [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-python/blob/master/samples/CollectionManagement/Program.py#L84) and the `rest api` from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/documentdb/create-a-collection).

```
import pydocumentdb;
import pydocumentdb.errors as errors
import pydocumentdb.document_client as document_client

config = {
    'ENDPOINT': 'https://***.documents.azure.com:443/',
    'MASTERKEY': '***'
};

# Initialize the Python DocumentDB client
client = document_client.DocumentClient(config['ENDPOINT'], {'masterKey': config['MASTERKEY']})


databaseLink = "dbs/db"
coll = {
        "id": "testCreate",
        "indexingPolicy": {
            "indexingMode": "lazy",
            "automatic": False
        },
        "partitionKey": {
            "paths": [
              "/AccountNumber"
            ],
            "kind": "Hash"
        }
       }
collection_options = { 'offerThroughput': 400 }
client.CreateCollection(databaseLink , coll, collection_options)
```

Hope it helps you.